# MD5Convert to hex char in C

Tags: c

```
void MD5Convert(unsigned char* BufferMD5, unsigned char* DstMD5, int size)
{
    unsigned char digest[16];
    char buf[32];
    
    int tmp_i;
    int counter_DstMD5 = 0;
    int i = 0;
    //16 +16 = 32
    char tmp_c[2];
    for (i; i < size; i++)
    {
        tmp_i = BufferMD5[i];
        //itoa(tmp_i, tmp_c, 16);
        sprintf_s(tmp_c, "%02X", BufferMD5[i]);
        DstMD5[counter_DstMD5] = tmp_c[0];
        counter_DstMD5++;
        DstMD5[counter_DstMD5] = tmp_c[1];
        counter_DstMD5++;   
    }
}
```

visual studio give me this following message:

"Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'tmp_c' was corrupted."

the code above doesn't work with visual studio + c, I've tried everything, but it ends up overflowing somewhere.

Sorry if the question was poorly worded, but I couldn't find a possible alternative

[see the code here](https://github.com/luismk/Dethon/blob/master/library.c#L40)

Comment: Note that your question would be of higher quality if you provided a [mre] of the problem.  The easiest way to do this would probably be to create a function `main` that does nothing else than create two arrays which it passes to the function `MD5Convert`. If you are able to reproduce the problem this way, then it would be more appropriate to post that example instead of your entire code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sprintf_s(tmp_c, "%02X", BufferMD5[i]);`

You need 3 characters to store two-character string as you need to accommodate null terminating character. `tmp_c` is too short and you write outside its bounds.

```
char tmp_c[3];
```

Comment: I'll test it now, if everything goes well, I'll mark it as a good answer